# Google app Update resulting in Speech Recognition problem

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, google-apps

I am trying to make an assistant and I am using the recognizer intent for speech recognition. Here is my code below:

```
private void _speak () {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.speech.RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(android.speech.RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, android.speech.RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(android.speech.RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(android.speech.RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hiiii, Tell Me SomeThing");
    try { startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT); }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {}
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(android.speech.RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                edittext2.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    if (edittext2.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        if (edittext3.getText().toString().equals("1")) {
            edittext3.setText("0");
        }
        else {
            edittext3.setText("1");
        }
    }
final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
private void nxt(){

}
```

The code should recognize the speech and display the result in an edit text and then trigger an action by changing the text of another edit text. It was working fine earlier. But as I **updated my google app** in my test devise the recognizing activity starts but doesn't give any result and nor changes the edit text. It simply starts listening and stops after listening the audio. I tried uninstalling the google app update and the code again works fine. I also checked google's **MyActivity** page where the transcript is shared and there the results were perfect.It could recognize the speech and showed me the correct transcripts.I searched a lot but couldn't find the solution. So, can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. After Google's last update it is now working fine. As I updated my Google app everything works fine now.